# Fixed positioning column in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic3

I am trying to position a menu within an ionic tablet application as 'fixed' and allow the adjacent column to scroll - without both of them scrolling.

Have been experimenting with Sass to setup fixed and sticky positioning but that is not working out so well. So instead I have given the left 'fixed' column a defined pixel height and then set the overflow in the right column to overflow.

However this technique is a bit 'hit and miss' considering the various tablet device dimensions. I attempted to use percentages for the height of the left column (`#SortingFilters`) but it did not work. Is there a proper solution for this? (Setting the height of left column to 100% is not working either).

Code is below:

**HTML page/view**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid no-padding>
        <ion-row>
            <ion-col col-3 ion-fixed id="sortingFilters">
                <h2>Sorting Filters</h2>
                <div id="accordion">
                    <div class="accordion-content-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="accordion-toggle dormantState" (click)="toggleIconSize()">Size <ion-icon id="collapseIcon" [name]="buttonIconSize"></ion-icon></h4>
                        <div class="accordion-content">
                            <p>Select whether the creature is microscopic or bigger than microscopic (can be seen with naked eye).</p>
                                <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="size">
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>All Sizes</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="all" value="" checked></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Microscopic</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="micro" value="micro" ></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Non Microscopic</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="nonmicro" value="nonmicro" ></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                </ion-list>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordion-content-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="accordion-toggle dormantState" (click)="toggleIconShell()">Shell <ion-icon [name]="buttonIconShell"></ion-icon></h4>
                        <div class="accordion-content">
                            <p>What type of shell does the creature have?</p>
                                <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="shell">
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>All Types</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="all" value="" checked></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>No Shell</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="no-shell" value="noshell"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Single Shell</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="single-shell" value="oneshell"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Double shell</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="double-shell" value="doubleshell"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                </ion-list>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordion-content-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="accordion-toggle dormantState" (click)="toggleIconLegs()">Legs <ion-icon [name]="buttonIconLegs"></ion-icon></h4>
                        <div class="accordion-content">
                            <p>How many pairs of legs does the creature have?</p>
                                <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="legs">
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>All Types</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="all" value="" checked></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>No legs</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="no-legs" value="nolegs"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>3 pairs</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="3pairs" value="threepairs"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>4+ pairs</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="4pairs" value="fourpairs"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                </ion-list>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordion-content-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="accordion-toggle dormantState" (click)="toggleIconTail()">Tail <ion-icon [name]="buttonIconTail"></ion-icon></h4>
                        <div class="accordion-content">
                            <p>Does the animal have a tail or not? If so, how many tails present?</p>
                                <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="tail" class="propertFilters">
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>All Types</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="all" value="" checked></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>No tail</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="no-tail" value="notail"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>1 tail</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="oneTail" value="onetail"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>2 tails</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="twoTail" value="twotail"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>3 tails</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="threeTail" value="threetail"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                </ion-list>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="accordion-content-wrapper">
                        <h4 class="accordion-toggle dormantState" (click)="toggleIconSense()">Sensitivity <ion-icon [name]="buttonIconSense"></ion-icon></h4>
                        <div class="accordion-content">
                            <p>How sensitive is the animal?</p>
                                <ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="sensitive" id="sensitivity">
                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>All Types</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="all" value="" checked></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Very Tolerant</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="veryTol" value="veryTol"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Tolerant</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="tolerant" value="tolerant"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Sensitive</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="sensitive" value="sensitive"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>

                                    <ion-item>
                                        <ion-label>Very Sensitive</ion-label>
                                        <ion-radio id="verySens" value="verySens"></ion-radio>
                                    </ion-item>
                                </ion-list>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <hr />
                <button ion-button full color="danger" icon-left (click)="resetFilter()">
                    <ion-icon name="refresh-circle"></ion-icon>Reset Filters
                </button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col style="background: white;" id="galleryDisplay">
                <ion-grid>
                    <ion-row>
                        <div *ngFor="let macro of allMacros">
                            <ion-col col-12 (click)="goToMacroDetailsPage(macro)" class="item filter-item" *ngIf="(size == macro.filter_size || !size) && (shell == macro.filter_shell || !shell) && (legs == macro.filter_legs || !legs) && (tail == macro.filter_tail || !tail) && (sensitive == macro.filter_sensitivity || !sensitive)">
                                <ion-card>
                                    <img src="./assets/imgs/thumbs/{{macro.thumbnail}}.jpg" />
                                    <ion-card-content>
                                        <ion-card-title>
                                            {{macro.title}}
                                        </ion-card-title>
                                    </ion-card-content>
                                </ion-card>
                            </ion-col>
                        </div>
                    </ion-row>
                </ion-grid>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>

</ion-content>
```

**and the SCSS file:**

```
page-filter {

    .content {

      height: 100%;

        .grid {

            #galleryDisplay {

              .grid {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: scroll;
                border: 1px solid pink;
                position: absolute;
              }

                .item {
                    width: 135px;
                    height: 165px;
                    background: #eee;
                    margin: 3px;
                    display: inline-flex;
                }

                .card-content {
                    padding: 10px;
                }

                .card-title {
                    font-size: 1.2rem;
                    font-weight: 500;
                    padding: 0;
                }

                .card {
                    margin: 3px;
                    width: 100%;
                }

                .filter-item {
                    animation: fadeInUp 0.6s;
                }
            }

            #sortingFilters {

                //overflow: hidden;
                padding: 1em;
                height: 700px;

                h2 {
                  color: #342392;
                    margin-top:0;
                }

                .accordion-content-wrapper {
                    border: 1px #488aff solid;
                    border-radius: 10px;
                    margin-bottom: 5px;

                    h4.accordion-toggle {
                      cursor: pointer;
                      color: #488aff;
                      padding: 8px;
                      margin-bottom: 0;
                      margin-top: 2px;

                      .icon {
                        float: right;
                      }
                    }

                    .accordion-content {
                      display: none;
                      padding: 5px;
                      p {
                        padding: 0px 5px;
                      }
                    }

                    .accordion-content.default {
                      display: block;
                    }

                    ul {
                      list-style-type: none;
                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue (reluctantly) with some javascript:

```
        var appHeaderHeight = $(".tabbar").css("top");
        appHeaderHeight = parseInt(appHeaderHeight, 10);
        var menuBarHeight = $(".tabbar").height();
        var deviceHeight = $(window).height();
        var galleryHeight = deviceHeight - appHeaderHeight - menuBarHeight;
        $("#galleryDisplay").css("height", galleryHeight);
```

Basically firing within the `on.ready()` handler to grab the various heights of elements and the screen and do some calculations, then set the height of the display column.

Not the most elegant solution, but did the job.